pre-commit version did not match created version on msys2
I would like to install pre-commit on msys2, I ran pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pre-commit successfuly but when I try to run it after pre-commit in a repo with hooks, I got the following error:
$ pre-commit run
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
An unexpected error has occurred: AssertionError: BUG: expected environment for python to be healthy immediately after install, please open an issue describing your environment

more info:

virtualenv python version did not match created version:
- actual version: <<error retrieving version from C:/Users/XYZ/.cache/pre-commit/repogzwwsprl/py_env-python3.11/Scripts/python.exe>>
- expected version: 3.11.9.final.0

Check the log at C:/Users/XYZ/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log

The log shows:
'''
version information
pre-commit version: 3.7.0
git --version: git version 2.45.1
sys.version:
    3.11.9 (main, Apr 12 2024, 09:55:31)  [GCC 13.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)]
sys.executable: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/python.exe
os.name: nt
sys.platform: win32

error information
An unexpected error has occurred: AssertionError: BUG: expected environment for python to be healthy immediately after install, please open an issue describing your environment

more info:

virtualenv python version did not match created version:
- actual version: <<error retrieving version from C:/Users/robin.maubert.ch2/.cache/pre-commit/repogzwwsprl/py_env-python3.11/Scripts/python.exe>>
- expected version: 3.11.9.final.0


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pre_commit/error_handler.py", line 73, in error_handler
    yield
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pre_commit/main.py", line 417, in main
    return run(args.config, store, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pre_commit/commands/run.py", line 442, in run
    install_hook_envs(to_install, store)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pre_commit/repository.py", line 238, in install_hook_envs
    _hook_install(hook)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pre_commit/repository.py", line 99, in _hook_install
    raise AssertionError(
AssertionError: BUG: expected environment for python to be healthy immediately after install, please open an issue describing your environment

more info:

virtualenv python version did not match created version:
- actual version: <<error retrieving version from C:/Users/XYZ/.cache/pre-commit/repogzwwsprl/py_env-python3.11/Scripts/python.exe>>
- expected version: 3.11.9.final.0

I have noted that there is no 'py_env-python3.11' in the mentioned folder
Any idea on how to get rid of that ?

I am a pre-commit user on Linux without any issue :/ No .gitignore issue I checked it carefuly too

this seems like a bug in the packaging of pre-commit for mingw which I have no control over.  that environment isn't supported fwiw and we only test against official windows pythons.  notably it seems that mingw python / virtualenv uses posix conventions for virtualenvs but pre-commit expects the windows conventions

ok, sould we create a support ticket or something ?

up to you, I would just use the windows pythons instead of mingw
